# Efficient numerical algorithms to find zeros of a highly nonlinear, smooth function

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Consider the root-finding problem:
$$f(x)=0$$
where $f(x)$ is a given smooth function which has several or infinite number of roots. We are interested in finding a finite $N$ number of roots in ascending order starting from 0. Assume the worse case; i.e. the function is highly nonlinear and there is no knowledge or initial guess for the roots. What efficient numerical method can find the roots with minimum number of function evaluations? Please provide reference for beginners (I study in engineering field and I only have basic knowledge in numerical methods).

Comment: I think at least some conditions on $f$ will be required to answer the question, otherwise there is really no good place to start. Is $f$ continuous? Differentiable? Smooth? Analytic? Also, $f$ is a scalar function on the reals, yes? i.e. $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @epiliam Yes, I should have added that the function is a real, continuous, smooth and infinitely differentiable function; for example, a linear combination of trigonometric functions (not necessarily in Fourier's series with harmonic periods).

Comment: Do you have any computational constraints?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi What is a highly nonlinear function?

Comment: @VanBaffo Only that the total number of function evaluations should be as less as possible; in other words, the numerical method is expected to converge fast. One other thing that is very important is that the method does not "miss" any root.

Comment: Maybe review - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms. Can you provide some examples of typical functions?

Comment: @PierreCarre When the function's behaviour is not predictable; for example it has too many oscillation in a tight interval while in a wide interval there is no root.

Comment: @Moo , For example:
$$f(t) = a_1cos(w_1t+b_1) + a_2cos(w_2t+b_2) + ... + a_ncos(w_nt+b_n)$$

Comment: The stated problem is very difficult and an extensive background in mathematics will be an asset. I recommend that you contact the lecturer how taught your last course on numerical analysis. This person will be more familiar with your educational background and should be able to offer recommendations that are truly helpful.

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi You should stick to nonlinear without any adjective, what you propose  is in no way a definition  in the mathematical sense. Moreover, this qualification is irrelevant for the problem at hand.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks for the advice. I'll try to contact a professor. But for now, Can you list the backgrounds required for the stated problem?

Comment: Interval analysis is one approach you can use which guarantees that you $^\star$find all of the roots, provided you can create functions over intervals as is the case with sinusoidal functions for example. Unless you have a more specific case where you can specifically test if $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[a,b]$ e.g. with polynomials, it's impossible to know if any roots exist in an interval. $^\star$Find in this case means deducing all subintervals $[a,b]$ s.t. $|b-a|$ is below some desired error and has potential to contain a root.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, Please name a reference with solved examples.

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi I don't have any references with examples, but you can find implementations such as "Julia's Interval Root Finding" package and algorithms such as the Interval Newton method. The concept is very simple to understand as well: if $0\notin f([a,b])$ then $[a,b]$ is guaranteed not to contain roots, and you can gradually narrow down your search regions until your desired accuracy.

Comment: FWIW tho, I'll point out the two major flaws with interval analysis that you might face. The first is that it computationally costs more to do calculations over entire intervals than it does for single values. The second is that it is not always readily available for your function or language. Implementing everything yourself from scratch can be a tall order.

Comment: In any case, I can write up a simple example of one of the algorithms later if you'd like me to.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you for your useful answers. I use MATLAB and I have no idea about Julia's programming (If it is fast-to-learn, it'd be great if you let me know from where to start). However if the basic algorithm is easy to understand, I'd appreciate if you introduce the concept through a simple example (trigonometric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Interval analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) is the numerical approach of using intervals of real values instead of individual real values. For example, if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f([-1,2])\subseteq[0,4]$ because $x\in[-1,2]\implies f(x)\in[0,4]$. This allows us to build bounds for the function over intervals. On the contrary, it also allows us to reject possible values, such as $0\notin f([1,2])$, implying no roots exist for $x\in[1,2]$.

Taking the example of $f(x)=x^2$, we can then bound its potential roots from the interval $[-1,2]$ using bisection. The first 3 iterations are shown below:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
[x,y]&f\left(\left[x,\frac{x+y}2\right]\right)&f\left(\left[\frac{x+y}2,y\right]\right)\\
\hline
[-1,2]&0\in[0,1]&
0\notin\left[\frac12,4\right]\\
\left[-1,\frac12\right]&0\notin\left[\frac1{16},1\right]&0\in\left[0,\frac14\right]\\
\left[-\frac14,\frac12\right]&0\in\left[0,\frac1{16}\right]&0\notin\left[\frac1{64},\frac14\right]
\end{array}

Some notable points about this example:

- There is only one root, but if there are multiple roots, then you would be able to find all of them.
- As the number of iterations increases, linear convergence to all of the roots are guaranteed.
- Although linear convergence is guaranteed, it is not any faster than bisection.
- It is easy to compute $f([x,y])$.

More advanced methods exist which give faster convergence. The Interval Newton method is one such example which extends the well-known Newton-Raphson method. It is worth noting however that these methods perform better when the function in question is very linear over the current interval. When this is not the case, the bisection method may be more robust.

Additionally, in this case it is very easy to compute $f([x,y])$ but this may not necessarily be the case depending on what your function is. For something like the Interval Newton method, you would have to compute $f'([x,y])$ instead, which may or may not be even messier.

To implement this yourself, the Wikipedia linked defines addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. As for $\sin([x,y])$ and $\cos([x,y])$, the following is a simple implementation in Python which can be easily translated into other languages.

```
import math

def cos(x, y):
    x_rounded = x % (2 * math.pi)
    y_rounded = (y - x) + x_rounded
    cos_x = math.cos(x_rounded)
    cos_y = math.cos(y_rounded)
    if x_rounded <= math.pi <= y_rounded or y_rounded >= 3 * math.pi:
        cos_lower = -1.0
    else:
        cos_lower = min(cos_x, cos_y)
    if x_rounded == 0 or y_rounded >= 2 * math.pi:
        cos_upper = 1.0
    else:
        cos_upper = max(cos_x, cos_y)
    return (cos_lower, cos_upper)

def sin(x, y):
    x_rounded = x % (2 * math.pi)
    y_rounded = (y - x) + x_rounded
    sin_x = math.sin(x_rounded)
    sin_y = math.sin(y_rounded)
    if x_rounded <= 1.5 * math.pi <= y_rounded or y_rounded >= 3.5 * math.pi:
        sin_lower = -1.0
    else:
        sin_lower = min(sin_x, sin_y)
    if x_rounded <= 0.5 * math.pi <= y_rounded or y_rounded >= 2.5 * math.pi:
        sin_upper = 1.0
    else:
        sin_upper = max(cos_x, cos_y)
    return (sin_lower, sin_upper)

# Examples:

print(cos(0, math.pi))
"""
(-1.0, 1.0)
"""

print(sin(0, math.pi))
"""
(0.0, 1.0)
"""
```

Comment: thank you for having time. I nearly understood. although how do we compute $f([x,y])$ for a complicated function such as this:
$$f(t) = a_1cos(w_1t+b_1) + a_2cos(w_2t+b_2) + ... + a_ncos(w_nt+b_n)$$
and I don 't understand how can the algorithm find multiple roots? If you could, please give another example (no need for computer program).

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi You just need to implement the trigonometric functions. The rest, like addition and multiplication, are defined in the Wikipedia link.

Comment: For finding multiple roots, you just keep track of multiple intervals at the same time. When an interval is small enough, save the result. Otherwise, if any interval remains, then split the interval and test for which sub-intervals to continue searching which.